# Why the following lines don't block the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdbc, event-dispatch-thread

```
    public lyridisplay (java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal); 

    initComponents();//to create a JList

   /* folowing code inside  try preforms DB operations*/
   /*It will return array of  string s*/
       try {
            s = insert.select();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(lyridisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(lyridisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    //now set the string s to JList

      jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings =s;
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });

     }
```

I think the above code should block the `EDT` , because of the DB operations before setting up `JList` and it runs on `EDT`.But It dosn't.The program runs smooth.I did similar thing before,resulting to blocked `EDT` and a frozen program.I preformed that code in a separate thread,as adviced by SO users.Why this code dosn't block `EDT`?

Comment: Indeed, it should block the EDT, but maybe that the select statement is too quick to feel any blocked status for the UI...

Comment: @ioan is the time taken by a select stmt. and insert stmt. same?Cause here i have 5-6 rows in result set,where as last time only one insert blocked my EDT

Comment: Why should it block? If `insert.select()` is quick enough then it won't block.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov last time one insert is blocking the EDT.But select gives many rows to result set...so..?

Comment: @joeyrohan sorry, didn't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov what i mean to say is,having a insert statement(just insert 1 row into database) blocked my EDT, where as,this select statement gives me many rows as output,but don't block EDT.Why so?

Comment: @joeyrohan it's hard to tell. But usually inserting data to database much slower then selecting values from it. So it's possible that select runs pretty fast.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov my answer here is for you, only EDT & Swing important rulles, not cabout oding or managements rulles

Comment: @joeyrohan: Nikita is right about the best case, but mKorbel is right about the worst case; off course, you have to code for the latter. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Swing GUI objects are constructed  on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT), the query very definitely blocks the EDT for some *indefinite* period of time. As noted in [*Memory Consistency Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility):

> Each action in a thread *happens-before* every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.

The problem is not how *short* the time is under ideal conditions, it's how *long* the time may become when things go awry. GUI users are very sensitive to EDT [liveness](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html); a [worker thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is good insurance against user dissatisfaction.